# Make an endless 2D map in Unity

Tags: unity3d-2dtools

Basically, the idea for my game roughly is this: Have a rocket launch from the ground, and slowly keep adding speed. As it rises higher and higher, I want the camera to follow the rocket, and then you can move the rocket to pick up special objects and avoid obstacles. So how do I create an ENDLESS map in Unity, so that my rocket won't fly off the map. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
// Singleton. Translates existing Obstacles and creates additional Obstacles.  
// The world moves around the player.

// When this object is collided into, the level pieces are deactivated.
// Level ends when all level pieces are deactivated

public class LevelTranslator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static LevelTranslator instance = null;

    // FIELDS
    public bool automaticallyStart = false;
    public bool isEndless = false;

    // Are all of the level pieces used?
    public bool levelOver
    {
        get
        {
            if (allLevelObjects.Count == 0)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }

    // Where all of the transforms are attached to
    public Transform levelParent = null;

    // Prefab to add to the level 
    public List<Transform> endlessLevelObject_Prefabs = null;

    // Where the level starts. ENDLESS!
    public Vector3 levelObjectOrigin = new Vector3();

    // The last created object. ENDLESS!
    public Transform lastCreatedObject = null;

    // Contains all of the transforms for the level
    public List<Transform> allLevelObjects = new List<Transform>();

    // Game Values
    public float speed = 5;
    public float objectSpacing = 5;                 // ENDLESS. How much object spacing there is between the current level piece and the going-to-spawn level piece
    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    public bool stopMoving = false;

    // Starts the level
    public void BeginMovingLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(BeginMovingLevel_Coroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator BeginMovingLevel_Coroutine()
    {
        while (!levelOver)
        {
            if (stopMoving)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
                continue;
            }

            // Moves the Transform Parent. All Objects will be attached to the parent, so it's moving the objects...
            levelParent.Translate(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);

            if (isEndless)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(lastCreatedObject.position, levelObjectOrigin) >= objectSpacing + Time.deltaTime)
                {
                    Transform t = Instantiate(endlessLevelObject_Prefabs[Random.Range(0, endlessLevelObject_Prefabs.Count)], levelObjectOrigin, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
                    t.parent = levelParent;
                    lastCreatedObject = t;
                    allLevelObjects.Add(t);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(lastCreatedObject.position, levelObjectOrigin) >= objectSpacing + Time.deltaTime)
                {
                    Transform t = allLevelObjects[0];
                    t.position = levelObjectOrigin;
                    t.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

                    t.parent = levelParent;
                    t.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                    lastCreatedObject = t;
                    allLevelObjects.Remove(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        instance = this;

        if (isEndless)
        {
            if (lastCreatedObject == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("ERROR! It's endless mode, but you didn't assign the lastCreatedObject to a starting object! You fucked up! (Well, it's okay, I did...)");
                return;
            }

            allLevelObjects.Add(lastCreatedObject);
            levelObjectOrigin = lastCreatedObject.position;
        }
        else
        {
            if (allLevelObjects.Count > 0)
                Debug.LogWarning("WARNING! There are no Objects in the allLevelObjects list! Place some there in order to avoid this error!");

            lastCreatedObject = allLevelObjects[0];
            allLevelObjects.Remove(lastCreatedObject);
            levelObjectOrigin = lastCreatedObject.position;
        }

        // Apply all of the Transforms to the parent
        if (automaticallyStart)
            BeginMovingLevel();
    }

    // Whenever an Obstacle collides with this... deactivate the colliding object.
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
    {
        Transform obstacleT = c.transform;
        if (allLevelObjects.Contains(obstacleT))
        {
            allLevelObjects.Remove(obstacleT);
        
            // "Destroys" the object
            obstacleT.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this awhile ago.

`levelParent` is a `GameObject`. Make it an empty GO. The `endlessLevelObject_Prefabs`... put in the level pieces you want to spawn.
`lastCreatedObject`. Set this to your FIRST level piece.

Answer (score 0):

To counter Heraclitus, not everything must flow.

For instance, how I handled this situation in the past is made my Main Character stay completely still, at fixed point 0,0,0, and I spawned the entire scene and moved the entire scene around my object. Instead of making your character move, make everything else move at that speed. It gives the illusion that you're moving while in fact staying still.

Depending on the complexity of what you need you may need to do a lot of manipulation of other objects outside of your ship.

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but if I keep the character still and move the scene, pretty soon the scene will move past the camera and then you will be staring into a void. So how to make an infinitely long scene?

Comment: You can continually generate more 'scene.' I made an endless map where I made a bunch of prefabs and continually instantiated more of them whenever one part of the scene moved too far. I also made a script that would destroy the "old" scene every time it moved too far away from the character. Split your scene into pieces and instantiate one whenever you destroy/deactivate one and you can replicate an infinite scene

Comment: Sounds great! Could you please share a bit of code? I'm very new to scripting, I barely made my own point counter lol